# Using std::net::UdpSocket with string url

Tags: rust, udp

I'm want to send a message by using udp protocol. I have an url like
this: `http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce`.

But in documentation and all examples that i saw the method `bind` only accept ip address and port.

It's possible to convert url address ?

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be using UDP? The URL you have in the example specifies HTTP.

Comment: I build a torrent client, all the network requets use udp. the url is a tracker url

Comment: [Although it does seem like `torrent.ubuntu.com` is using TCP.](https://pastebin.com/saCpNi6d)
In my torrent client, I see both `http://` and `udp://` trackers.

Answer (score 0):

The `bind` functions works with anything that implements [`ToSocketAddrs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html).

From the documentation, you can use a hostname/port string with this trait:

> Creating a [`SocketAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.SocketAddr.html) iterator from a hostname:
>
> ```rust
> use std::net::{SocketAddr, ToSocketAddrs};
>
> // assuming 'localhost' resolves to 127.0.0.1
> let mut addrs_iter = "localhost:443".to_socket_addrs().unwrap();
> assert_eq!(addrs_iter.next(), Some(SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 443))));
> assert!(addrs_iter.next().is_none());
>
> // assuming 'foo' does not resolve
> assert!("foo:443".to_socket_addrs().is_err());
> ```

However the link `http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce` is a [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) URL, and it is extremely uncommon to use UDP with HTTP, but assume this server does listen on UDP, you could connect to it using `UdpSocket::bind("torrent.ubuntu.com:6969")`.

Comment: thanks for the help but UdpSocket::bind("torrent.ubuntu.com:6969") give me an error `{ code: 99, kind: AddrNotAvailable, message: "Cannot assign requested address" } `

Comment: Well, yes actually that's normal. `bind` is meant to be used on the *server*, not the client. The client is supposed to use [`connect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.connect).

Comment: Are you sure ? I see in the docs that you can use connect only with sockets and sockets are always create by a bind.

Comment: **Listening** sockets are created by `bind`. That's not what you are doing here.